# FlowChart in Nuxt, how to do?

Tags: nuxtjs3

I need a plugin in Nuxt3, where I can make flowcharts like the FlowChart of GoJs, how could I solve this issue, some use case?

have not found anything yet uqe could try.

Comment: Hi, what did you tried so far?

Comment: Hello, I got with the gojs